# Azure Function RabbitMq trigger stops receiving messages

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, azure-functions

I have Azure Function with RabbitMq trigger and it stops receiving any messages after certain time. The function is deployed in Azure. When I stop and then start again the function, it starts pulling messages again, but after a while it stops. When I run it locally on my machine the problem never occurs. My code looks like this:

```
    [FunctionName(nameof(Bets))]
    public async Task Bets([RabbitMQTrigger(nameof(Bets), ConnectionStringSetting = "RabbitConnection")] BasicDeliverEventArgs args,
        [RabbitMQ(ConnectionStringSetting = "RabbitConnection")] IModel client, ILogger log)
    {
        var myQueueItem = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(args.Body);
        var logEntry = new Log()
        {
            date = DateTime.UtcNow,
            status = SuccessStatus,
            input = myQueueItem,
            queue = nameof(Bets)
        };
        try
        {
            var input = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Bet[]>(myQueueItem);
            await _context.BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync(input);
            log.LogInformation($"Finished input save: {myQueueItem}");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            client.BasicNack(args.DeliveryTag, false, true);
            logEntry.status = "Error";
            logEntry.error = e.Message;
            log.LogError(e, e.Message, myQueueItem);
        }

        await _context.logs.AddAsync(logEntry);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to configure within your function app configuration under general settings tab the option "always on" which Prevents your app from being idled out due to inactivity.